# Using microphone to interact with web page

Tags: flash, audio, applet

I am looking for advice how to set web pages where user can interact with it using microphone. The aim would be that user can say word and the word would be recorder and the file compared on server with another sound (word) and then the result (the searched word) would be displayed. It would be a spoken dictionary.

Comment: You want to make google voice search? That sounds like a pretty complicated project!

Comment: PHP cannot interact with hardware on the client side. Try Flash.

Comment: You may want to look at a Java Applet for this, PHP cannot interact with remote hardware but a client side Java applet can. I would suggest doing a few searches in Google to see if it will work for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this currently is to build a Flash application that records microphone audio.  Now, you don't have to build the whole thing in Flash... your Flash movie can interact with JavaScript from there.  But, Flash is the only way to record audio client-side, short of a Java applet or browser plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I have found [FlashWavRecorder] (https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder) that records the voice and sends it to server. Now I need to compare this new audio file with files (22000) on server as voice recognition. Would anyone suggest some easy implementation? Tx in advance

Comment: @chejnik, post that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this page http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1151 and this zip http://www.didierbrun.com/VOICE_GESTURE.zip (it could be a starting point).